# width 100% bootstrap responsivo

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css3, layout-responsivo, grid

Estou usando o bootstrap pelo seu grid fluido, usei o `row-fluid` fora do `container-fluid` pra ele ficar sem a margem habitual. Na resolução do desktop o rodapé fica normal com o width 100%, mas quando diminui a resolução ele ganha a margem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>titulo</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/blueberry.css">
    <link href="img/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="blueberry" class="blueberry span12 centralizado">   
            <ul class="slides">
                <li><img src="img/img1.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="img/img3.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="img/img2.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 andro-saude">
        <h2><a href="">Area 1</a></h2>
        <hr/>
        <ul class="span10 centralizado">
            <li class="well span3 info">
                <img src="img/logo-cabeca.png">
                <a><h3>Título</h3></a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora veniam beatae, aspernatur aut architecto, obcaecati, delectus in optio id repellendus molestiae, amet soluta natus fugiat nisi nihil at debitis mollitia.</p>
                <h5>13 de janeiro de 1223</h5>
            </li>
            <li class="well span3 info"></li>
            <li class="well span3 info"></li>
            <li class="well span3 info"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 rodape">
        <div class="span4 desenvolv">
           <p>Desenvolvimento</p>
           <a href="#" target="blank"><img src="img/cpc.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <h4>Nome</h4>
            <p>Endereço</p>
            <p>Contato</p>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <ul class="sociais">
                <li><a href=""><img src="img/social (1).png"></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="img/social (2).png"></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="img/social (3).png"></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="img/social (4).png"></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="img/social (5).png"></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="img/social (6).png"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.blueberry.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.blueberry').blueberry({interval: 4000, duration: 4000});
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Código? Vai ajudar..

Comment: Não relacionado à pergunta: reparei que todas as suas tags `script` estão fora do `body`. Deveriam estar dentro, não?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reparei que na resolução `xs` o `body` recebe um `padding-left` e `padding-right` de `20px`. Isso está fazendo com que a "margem" apareça. Experimente setá-los para zero, manualmente:

```
body {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xd23vmxp/).

**Atualização:** Nessa mesma resolução `xs`, os elementos do tipo `navbar` recebem uma margem negativa de `20px` para "compensar" o padding de `20px` no `body`. De modo que é necessário atribuí-los também para zero, caso a mudança acima seja feita:

```
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom, .navbar-static-top {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xd23vmxp/2/). Caso você encontre o mesmo problema com outros componentes, sugiro a seguinte sequência de passos para depurar (foi o que eu fiz para chegar a essa resposta):

1. Abra seu exemplo no Chrome (outros browsers devem ter recursos semelhantes);
2. Clique com o botão direito no elemento "mal-formatado" e escolha "Inspecionar Elemento";

   - Se necessário, escolha seu elemento pai (às vezes o Inspecionar Elemento cai em um descendente do elemento problemático).
3. À direita, em "Styles" procure pela regra correspondente à resolução desejada do Bootstrap:

   - `xs` - `@media (max-width: 767px)`
   - `sm` - `@media(min-width:768px)` e `(max-width:991px)`
   - `md` - `@media(min-width:992px)` e `(max-width:1199px)`
   - `lg` - `@media(min-width:1200px)`

   (Nota: esses valores são referentes à versão atual do Bootstrap - 3.X - a versão 2.X pode usar valores ligeiramente diferentes)
4. Uma dessas regras com certeza será a "problemática" - pois são elas que se aplicam a uma resolução de tela em particular, e não às outras.

Comment: Mas ai se eu tiver uma navbar ela fica pra "fora" da janela.

Comment: @ClaraBatt Nesse caso é só ajustar o CSS do navbar também. Você tem um exemplo de navbar onde esse problema acontece, pra eu testar? A propósito, você está usando o Bootstrap 2.x ou 3.x?

Comment: Tô usando o bootstrap 2, dá uma olhada: http://jsfiddle.net/xd23vmxp/1/

Comment: @ClaraBatt Atualizei a resposta. Como imaginava, o navbar aplicava um estilo contrário ao do body para "compensar". A solução é simplesmente desfazer isso também.